# Laravel 8 - Bootstrap 5 Bootstrap-select dont show options

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-select

I am trying to set bootstrap-select in laravel via laravel mix. Everything seems correct, but when clicking on the select, it does not show the options.

In resources/js/Bootstrap.js I add the libs, popper before jquery and bootrstrap and bootstrap-select later.

```
const { popper } = require('@popperjs/core');

window._ = require('lodash');
   

try {
    require('bootstrap');
    window.$ = require('jquery');
    window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    require("jquery-datetimepicker");
    require("bootstrap-select");


} catch (e) {}
```

In the blade template I have the following code:

```
        <select class="form-control" id="user" data-live-search="true">
            <option value="0">one</option>
            <option value="1">optionX</option>
            <option value="2">optionX</option>
            <option value="3">optionX</option>
            <option value="4">optionX</option>
            <option value="5">optionX</option>
        </select>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('select').selectpicker();
    });        

</script>
```

It seems that everything is correct, the select is shown, and there are no errors in the console, but pressing does not show the options.

Comment: Have you tried using `form-select` instead of `form-control`? From https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/select/: "_Custom `<select>` menus need only a custom class, `.form-select` to trigger the custom styles._" What is `.selectpicker()` supposed to do, is it from a package?

Comment: With the form-select class, it looks completely wrong, one select inside another. Bootstrap-select, is a plugin that when click a select, the options are shown, and a search engine above. https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/tree/main

Comment: My fault, sorry, didn't realize bootstrap-select was a plugin/package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 5 doesn't work with Bootstrap-select 1.13.xxx. I had to grab one of beta/RC to get it to work with Laravel 8 and Bootstrap 5

I used

```
npm install bootstrap-select@next
```

Hope this helps